# 3-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ which intersects the ellipsoid in a sphere?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem: In the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^4$ consider the ellipsoid:

$$
2{x_{1}}^2 + 3{x_{2}}^2 + 4{x_{3}}^2 + 5{x_{4}}^2 = 1
$$

Is there a 3-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ which intersects the ellipsoid in a sphere?

What I thought is that if I degenerate the ellipsoid in each coordinate, like, $x_4=0$, first, and analyze the 3-dimensional generated ellipsoid. If I do this in each coordinate, I will look that the minimal distance at origin isn't constant for all, and it can't form circumferences in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, I can't generate a sphere, because can't generate circumferences. So, I would help to my solution and look a alternative solution.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: So, i think degenerate the ellipsoid in each coordinate, like, $x_4 = 0$ first, and analyze the 3-dimensional generated ellipsoid. And, if I do this in each coordinate, I will look that the minimal distance at origin isn't constant for all, and it can't form circumferences in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, I can't generate a sphere, because can't generate circumferences. So, I would help to my solution and look a alternative solution. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to describe all of the 3-dimensional subspaces (there are more than just the coordinates), and compute the equations defining the intersection of that Ellipsoid with the subspace? Do you know how to tell if an equation in 3 variables defines a sphere? Maybe analyzing these questions would be a good place to start.

Comment: No, I don't think another solution, AreaMan. I , frankly, lost myself in this problem. I know describe the sphere like $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {||xi-\alpha_i||}^2 = R^2, (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ is the sphere's centre. Can I minimize $ f(x) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}<x-\alpha_i,x-\alpha_i> $, with lagrange multiplier, and use it to part of the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is “no”: A 3-dimensional subspace will intersect the plane $x = y = 0$ in a subspace of dimension $≥ 1$, and therefore it will contain a point from the ellipse $4z^2 + 5u^2 = 1$, all of whose points lie ≤ 1/2 away from the origin. Likewise, the same 3-dimensional section will contain another point, from ellipse $2x^2 + 3y^3 = 1$ (in the plane $z = u = 0$), all of whose points lie $> 1/2$ away from the origin. Thus, the section is not a sphere.